# mongodb find all documents with a field equal to one of the given array elements

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have three documents in a collection of mongodb like below:

{
book: "a"
},
{
book: "b"
},
{
book: "c"
}

I want a query that gives all documents that their book field value is a member of a given array. For example if the given array is ["a", "c", "d"], the query must return the first and the third document as result because "a" and "c" are members of array.

Is there a query for this to do it all at once or the only way is to loop over the given array and use a simple find query?

Comment: That's the perfect case for the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see $in operator
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

in your case

```
db.books.find( { book: { $in:["a", "c", "d"]} } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by using the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

In the mongo shell this would look like
`db.<collectionName>.find({ book: { $in: [ "a", "c", "d" ] }})`